# Nested MasterPages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Currently I have two MasterPages.  One is the child of the other.

Parent:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Parent.master.cs" Inherits="Parent.Parent" %>
```

Parent Code Behind:

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Parent: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Child:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Parent.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Child.master.cs" Inherits="Child.Master" %>
```

Child Code Behind:

```
public partial class Child : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
```

I'm still getting 
"Parser Error Message: 'UserMasterPage' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'"

Any Help?

Comment: Did the changes/answer help?

Comment: Sadly, not.  I replied to your Answer with what I'm currently running into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED with new information**

If your class is declared as

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Parent: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
```

than you should inherit from the Project namespace and then the class Parent:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Parent.master.cs" Inherits="Project.Parent" %>
```

They must have a direct match otherwise it will not find the class for your master page.

---

**Examples:**
In the scenario where you have your class inside of a namespace:

```
namespace Project {
    public partial class Parent : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
```

you will use `Project.Parent`

But if you just have:

```
public partial class Child: System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
```

Then you will just use `Child`

Comment: @KevinFischer you have `Inherits="Child.Master" ` instead of `Inherits="Child"` or is that incorrect? If you have `Inherits="Child"` than could you please update your code in the question?

Comment: Oh you're right!  Let me check to see if that worked

Comment: I added a bit more of an explanation so you can see why you wuold or would not use that :)

Comment: Error Message:Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Parent.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Child.master.cs" Inherits="Child" %>

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you're saying.  Whatever my Inherits="(this)" should be the same as public partial class (this) : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {...}

Comment: So I did that for my Parent and I'm still throwing the error:
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Parent.master.cs" Inherits="Parent" %>

Where my Inherits= changed from Project.Parent to Parent, still No Joy.

Comment: For your parents page, because you have your class in a namespace you MUST call the namespace first. Your namespace is **Project** and your class is **Parent**. So if you `Inherits="Project.Parent"` You should not get that error. The same applies for your child page. If it has a namespace, you must include it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63058/discussion-between-termato-and-kevin-fischer).